# Function OutputType

Tags: powershell

How works  OutputType attribute?

```
function test
{
  [OutputType([Bool])]
  Param ($a)

  return $a
}

$one = test 1
$two = test 0

$one.GetType() # Int32
$two.GetType() # Int32
```

I expected $one is true, $two is false.

Comment: That's because you're confusing what `[OutputType([Bool])])` is for. It doesn't have affect on the object output *directly*. You need to type constrain the parameter: `Param ([bool]$a)`

Comment: OutputType is a hint for the console to help with tab-completion.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on the helpful comments by [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) and [Mike Shepard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36429/mike-shepard):

As the conceptual [about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute) help topic indicates:

- The **`[OutputType()]` attribute does *not* control a function or script's actual output data type**.

  - **PowerShell offers *no* way to declare an enforced "return type"** the way languages such as C# do: while it makes sense to constrain and document what a function or script outputs ("returns"), it is technically free to output any number of objects, of any type, simply by writing to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
  - By contrast, **you *can* enforce the data type of *input*** provided to a function or script, namely by *type-constraining its parameter definitions*; for instance, you could ensure that arguments passed to your `-a` parameter are Booleans to begin with, by replacing `param($a)` with `param([bool] $a)`, as Abraham notes - see the conceptual [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters) help topic.
- Instead, **the `[OutputType()]` attribute only has *informational* character**:

  - It adds *metadata* to a function definition listing the output type(s), which features such as PowerShell's help system and tab-completion can make use of.
  - **It is up to the function / script author to make sure that the types listed via `[OutputType()]` reflect the *actual* output data types**.

    - Therefore, the information may be incorrect - as it was in your case, accidentally.

---

Therefore, your function needs to ensure that the desired data type is output *as part of the output statement*:

```
function test
{
  [OutputType([bool])]
  Param ($a) # $a is allowed to be of any type (no type constraint present)

  # Output a [bool] explicitly.
  # Note: No strict need for `return` here, 
  #       thanks to PowerShell's implicit output behavior.
  [bool] $a
}
```